# What is "article" I see on profile pages?

Tags: support

I suddenly noticed that there's a group called "Articles", aside from "All" "Questions" "Answers" in my [profile page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4223/yosh?tab=profile) (scroll down a bit):

[image]

Interestingly, the link that says "View all questions, answers, and [**articles**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4223/yosh?tab=articles)" leads to a page-not-found page. I checked other notable users' profiles, and the situation is the same.

No mentions of this functionality is found on the help page. I'm assuming it's something that is being tested on other stackexchange sites, although I wasn't able to find any information in the meta.stackexchange site.

- What is this?
- This "article" concept doesn't seem to be adopted to Japanese Language stackexchange (yet), am I right?
- Will it be coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Articles are official posts from the companies that own the collectives to which articles belong. This is a feature only on Stack Overflow where a company can obtain certain tags relating to its products, and that allows them to write official answers and endorse certain answers. (To be clear, articles are separate posts, sort of like blog posts, where companies can discuss roadmaps, upcoming features, etc. There are only a handful of articles in existence as of right now.)

I'm not sure if it's intended that articles show on profiles elsewhere than SO... I also don't think we know yet if this feature is planned to be added to other sites.

Comment: So there's [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives), under which articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/69193717/how-to-use-external-status-checks-for-merge-requests) are posted. The help centre on Stack Overflow has [an article for this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-what-are). Thank you!